# changing port not working in vuejs project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I have made a sample app in vuejs and try to change the port number. However this seems not to work as I get connection refused on that particular port, like nothing is being served on that port.

So I made a `vue.config.js` file in the root of my vuejs project.
This config file looks like this:

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
outputDir: './dist/',

chainWebpack: config => {

    config.optimization
        .splitChunks(false)

    config
        .plugin('BundleTracker')
        .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: '../frontend/webpack-stats.json'}])

    config.resolve.alias
        .set('__STATIC__', 'static')

    config.devServer
        .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
        .host('0.0.0.0')
        .port(8080)
        .hotOnly(true)
        .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
        .https(false)
        .headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["\*"]})
        }
    };
```

When I do 'npm run serve', I get the following:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:21739/ 
  - Network: http://0.0.0.0:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

The port at 21739 is working but the one at 8080 is not working?
Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here, or did I forget something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a somewhat hacky fix. In node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js there is this line that defines the port it is like:

```
const port = await portfinder.getPortPromise()
```

I have changed it to

```
const port = args.port || process.env.PORT || projectDevServerOptions.port
```

Now everything loads well. Don't know why they choose that approach and if there is a better way to handle this i'd like to know.